# 2D array padding to avoid conflict cache misses

Tags: caching, padding, conflict

I have been studding topics related to conflict misses due to limited associativity of caches. According to: 
[1] http://www.jilp.org/vol6/v6paper7.pdf

" a major problem with tiling is that limited cache associativity may cause data in a tile to be mapped onto the same cache line, even though there is sufficient space in the cache. Conflict misses will result, causing tile data to be evicted from cache before they may be reused"

In other papers i have read that the conflict misses are mostly appearing when we have arrays with a size of power of 2. Moreover I know that the address in a set associative cache is composed of the TAG field (A31-A9) , the SET field (A8-A5) and the OFFSET field (A4-A0), supposing that we have 128 slots divided by 8 slots per set.

To find a particular byte we have first to find the corresponding set.We use the address bits A9 – A5 to identify the set. The 4 less significant bits of the address is the offset within a slot. The tag is used to identify a slot within a set. If we want to store a new block we first identify the set and then according to a replacement policy we store the block to a cache line of the particular set.

So i guess that two blocks of memory with the same A8-A5 bits will map to the same set and thus there is a possibility of having a cache conflict. The offset field is composed of 2^5 = 32 combinations. Or in other words the offset is representing the byte inside a cache line. So that means, every 512/32=16 blocks(or cache lines) from the memory will map to the same set. Is my reasoning correct, if we consider 1-way associative cache (direct map)?

Moreover why do we have conflict misses especially for arrays that have a size of power of 2? And can someone explain to me how padding eliminates these conflict misses? I understand that padding will result to something like figure 7 of [1], but i cannot understand how. Where is the padding applied exactly? Is it applied in the end of the array or every 512 bytes? I am apologize in advance for the naive question.